# Can we inject property at NextRequest in Next.js

Tags: typescript, next.js, app-router

```
import { DefaultSession } from "next-auth";

declare module "next-auth" {
  interface Session {
    user: {
      id: string;
    } & DefaultSession["user"];
  }
}
```

Like this code, we inject the user object inside `next-auth` while using this while accessing `session.user.id` `TypeScript` does not complain about type.I am using app router and next version is `"next": "14.0.4"`